# Fourier Series Concept

Tags: math, fourier

[image]

Hello, I am learning about the Fourier Transform, and I can do the math, but I'm having trouble with the fundamental concepts. From my understanding, the Fourier transform allows us to see the frequency components of a time signal, with "peaks" in the graph corresponding to the frequency components.

However, I am not understanding the Fourier transform of a rectangular pulse. Its a sinc graph with a large peak at f = 0, and little peaks gradually fading out at higher frequencies. Can someone help explain the significance of the graph? For instance, why is there the large peak at f = 0? Why is there also not a peak at f = 1, wouldn't that be the frequency of the rectangular pulse?

Comment: I recommend you spent a moment and listen to [this visual introduction](https://youtu.be/spUNpyF58BY) by Grant Sanderson. If you think about the winding frequency here at DC, it means all of the vectors lie exactly on the real axis and you are just summing up the area of the pulse, which here is 1. But as you increase the winding frequency, more and more of the vector length of 1 (for the parts that aren't 0), lay partly in the imaginary directions leaving less along the real axis, so the real sum part declines. Etc. Watch the video. Then watch [another](https://youtu.be/r6sGWTCMz2k) good one.

Comment: @jonk I watched that Grant Sanderson video prior to that post, which is why I'm a little confused (I know I probably don't quite understand it). In the video after taking the fourier transform, the peaks in the graph corresponded to whatever frequecies of the signals were in the original. So what I don't understand is what do the peaks correspond to in the example above in the post. Why the peak at f=0? Why not f=1 (From my understanding the frequency of the original signal is 1, given that it lasts one second)

Comment: I think there are two important details that Grant left out of the video that might help you. One is the whole idea of infinitesimals and calculus and a geometric way of seeing it, instead of the Rube-Goldberg crap that Weierstrass and Dedekind thrust upon us back in the mid to late 1800's. It's so much cleaner to see calculus when you think in pictures than in nasty algebra. So that's one I'd "fix up." The other is that he didn't actually show you what happens with the winding frequency of 0 (or very very near zero.) You need to see what's really happening there.

Comment: I could write something up about it. But it would take a while to provide a close examination of these two essential ideas. I'd need to start by destroying calculus as it is usually taught (algebraically) and rebuilding it back up as a purely geometric set of concepts, instead. (There is a provable 1:1 relationship between the set of all algebra problems and the set of all geometric problems.) Then I'd need to let you "see" for the first time what Grant was doing there and how a frequency of zero can function as a winding frequency. Might be worth the time. Not sure. I could try a bit to see.

Comment: @jonk There are really good reasons that visual explanations of things have fallen out of favor in mathematics. Even the word geometric means things like differential geometry instead of what the Greeks did. The thing about visualizations is that they work intuitively in Euclidean spaces, but break down in other topologies. You come to completely wrong conclusions. In particular, we want to be able to do differentiation and integration on sets rather than on numbers. For that we need measure spaces. Hence things become abstract and difficult to visualize.

Comment: @ClockwerkSC Just because something lasts for one second does not imply that it has a frequency of 1 Hz. For example, a 1 GHz sine wave that is on for one second.

Comment: @user110971 We each have our experiences. I'll mention one. I was in my first week as a new contractor to the company that made the first successful rewritable CD. They were polymer chemist PhDs, optical PhDs, etc. I was to write the vector light simulator for them. (Saves money not having to build something over and over.) End of 1st week I ask a simple question. Lead optical guy answers, walks away, comes back a half hour later and orders me into his office. "Why did you ask that question?", he asked. "I was curious," I said. He replied, "It took us 18 months to ask that question."

Comment: @user110971 Seeing math visually may be helpful. But there is no "best way" to go. And different people have different talents. Some are very, very adept at algebraic manipulation. Some are very, very adept at seeing in a more visual manner. Some can't see the forest for the trees and take the long way around the barn. Some are insightful, instead. But calculus was invented by physicists for physical problems. And in that sense, is quite intuitive. Dedekind and Weierstrass, my opinion, sucked the life out of it. Abraham Robinson, in Non-Standard Analysis in early 1960's, brings that life back.

Comment: @ClockwerkSC There are 3 factors Fourier. The f(x) scaler, the e^(stuff) rotating unit vector, and dx; multiplied. The unit vector is scaled and finite, multiplying by an infinitely narrow dx. Using only the real part, this is just a narrow rectangle with finite height and infinitesimal width. The summation is just stacking these rectangles side-by-side to make an area. When winding at f=0, Euler's is just 1, so it's just side-by-side stacking of the narrow rectangles. So you get back the original area of your pulse. At f=1 the unit vector rotates, less is real, and that's why you see less.

Comment: @jonk In this case there is a best way. Mathematicians worked really hard for many years to find it. I was just pointing out some of the problems they ran into and why the reformulation was necessary.

Comment: @user110971 Okay. Well, the OP is "trying to understand." I think a lighter, more geometric approach might help. But frankly, I don't know for sure. So we'll leave it there, I suppose. By the way, I don't think mathematicians at one point in time (say, Dedekind and Weierstrass, for example) always have the final say about what is better. In this case, I think Abraham Robinson's treatment a century later is actually much, much more understandable while at the same time fully grounded on solid mathematical theory. (Newton's fluxions were not so well grounded, but were quite understandable.)

Answer (score 0):

The function is an impulse, which is a vanishingly narrow pulse centered at t=0, but with finite area, in the time domain.

So the interpretation is that the Fourier transform of the impulse is the sum of an infinite number of cosines at different frequencies that cancel out everywhere except at t=0.

In the case of the non-ideal rectangular pulse, the cosines have to add up to the rectangular pulse around t=0 and nowhere else. The pulse only happens once, so the center frequency is zero.

Answer (score 0):

No, the peaks are not the sole frequency components. The Fourier transform allows one to express a function as a sum (integral really, but don’t let the mathematicians here you say otherwise or they’ll bite your head off) of different frequencies.

$$f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) e^{j\omega t}\ \mathrm{d}f.$$

In particular, each frequency element \$F(\omega) e^{j\omega}\$ has a component \$F(\omega)\$. Think of \$e^{j\omega}\$ as a basis vector and \$F(\omega)\$ as the component of \$f(t)\$ in the direction of \$e^{j\omega}\$. This is similar to how you have an \$x\$ basis vector in Euclidean space, but instead you have infinitely many bases for each value of \$\omega\$. Hence you are plotting \$F(\omega)\$ in your graph. So for each value of \$\omega = 2\pi f\$ you can find the value of \$F(\omega)\$, which is the component of \$f(t)\$ in the direction of the \$e^{j\omega}\$ basis vector.

Comment: What are the significances of the peaks and zero crossings of the graph of the Fourier transform then?

Comment: Peaks are frequencies that have more energy than the ones immediately before/after them do.  Zeros are frequencies that have no energy at all.

Comment: @ClockwerkSC Peaks are where |F| attains a local maximum and zeros are where F is zero. Just like a time domain sine wave has peaks and zeros.

Answer (score 0):

the Fourier is just a correlation between two functions; that is, multiply and accumulate the result.

The correlation between two identical (frequency and phase) sinusoids is very strong.

The correlation between sin(X * time) and sin (3X * time) is 1/3

The correlation between sin(X * time) and sin(5X * time) is 1/5